# Jquery: Body background scrolling to the left?

Tags: jquery

I'm breaking my head trying to make this work. I want my page's body background to scroll sideways.

```
<html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("body").animate({backgroundPosition : "500 0"}, 2000);
});
</script>

<body style="background-image: url('bg.jpg')">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use an absolutely position `<img />` tag instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077429/jquery-css-background-position-animation

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot animate css properties that takes 2 or more values.

You can use `backgroundPositionY` and `backgroundPositionX` to animate vertically and horizontally:

```
$("body").animate({backgroundPositionY : "500px"}, 2000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xBhuT/)**

Comment: It works also in Safari and Chrome. Only Opera and Firefox have no support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create this effect in all browsers, you can try a different approach like this;

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="background" id="background"></div>
  <div class="page-content">Put your content here</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.background {
  background-image:url('bg.jpg');
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
.page-content {
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var animateWidth = '500'        
  $('#background').height(windowHeight).width(windowWidth)
    .animate({
      left: animateWidth + 'px',
      width: (windowWidth - animateWidth) + 'px'
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HHgKW/3/